# Changing the language of my application only works once

Tags: flutter, widget, settings

I am making a Flutter application and I am making a settings page where I want to allow the user to choose the language they want. I have already tried many things but each time I have the same problem: I can only change the language once.

Here is my "settings" view:

```
class SettingViewState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
  String _selectedLanguage = 'French';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('SettingViewState - build');

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavDrawableWidget(),            // Hamburger menu
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text('\n${AppSettings.strings.settingTitle}\n',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 2),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(AppSettings.strings.languageTitle),
                leading: Icon(Icons.language),
                trailing: Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                    canvasColor: Colors.blue[50],
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _selectedLanguage,
                    items: [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'French',
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(AppSettings.APP_FRENCH_FLAG,width: 30, height: 20,),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Text(AppSettings.strings.frenchTitle),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'English',
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(AppSettings.APP_ENGLISH_FLAG,width: 30, height: 20,),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Text(AppSettings.strings.englishTitle),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedLanguage = newValue ?? _selectedLanguage;
                        AppSettings.changeLanguage(_selectedLanguage);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my method in my config file to change the language:

```
  static void changeLanguage(String newLanguage) 
  {
    APP_LANGUAGE = newLanguage;
  }
```

Thanks in advance if you take the time to answer me and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Riverpod an option for your state management?

https://riverpod.dev/

I believe you can achieve what you want similar to the following:

**state_providers.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final selectedLanguageProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => 'English');
```

**setting_view.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:yourapp/providers/state_providers.dart';

class SettingViewState extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SettingViewState({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final selectedLanguage = ref.watch(selectedLanguageProvider);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 2),
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            title: const Text('Language'),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.language),
            trailing: Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                canvasColor: Colors.blue[50],
              ),
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: selectedLanguage,
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'French',
                    child: Text('French'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'English',
                    child: Text('English'),
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  ref.read(selectedLanguageProvider.notifier).state = newValue!;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It would also simplify accessing the state across Widgets as opposed to using a static settings file which I imagine you are doing. For example you can access the language state directly in an app bar widget

**common_app_bar.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:yourapp/providers/state_providers.dart';

class CommonAppBar extends ConsumerWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CommonAppBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final selectedLanguage = ref.watch(selectedLanguageProvider);

    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      elevation: 0,
      title: Text(selectedLanguage == 'English' ? 'Hello' : 'Bonjour'),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll try to do that. But how do I manage this for all my apps? Do I have to do these imports in all my files? 
```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:yourapp/providers/state_providers.dart';
```

Comment: anywhere you want to access or set the state, yes. Riverpod is a shared package so needs to be imported like any package. For your use case above, it possibly seems overkill to introduce it. But if you maintain a lot of state in your apps, then I would suggest it is worth using, especially for streaming firestore updates etc...

Comment: If it's overkill to introduce it in my case, and knowing that I won't use it for anything else since I'm finalizing my app, isn't there a better, simpler solution?